# Is there a Standard Untokenize Templated Type?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a standard type to untokenize a type? It'd probably be implemented as so:

```
template<class T>
using untokenize = T;
```

This way I can perform the following cast using an overloaded operator:

```
struct x {
  int y;
  operator int&() {
    return y;
  }
};

x a;
// int&(a); // doesn't work
// (int&)(a); // not the same thing
untokenize<int&>(a); // works great
```

Or is there another, more standard way to achieve my goal of avoiding a c-style cast in favor of a function-style cast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be more idiomatic to use the correct "named cast" in general. Here, `static_cast` is appropriate:

```
static_cast<int&>(a);
```

That said, there *is* a standard template that works the same as your other approach, [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity), but only as of C++20:

```
std::type_identity_t<int&>(a);
```

Answer (score 9):

`static_cast<T>` does what you're asking for.